# Batch Write to Firestore: Document aren't write completely

Tags: scala, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-dataflow, batch-processing

I have started learning and using Scala. I'm creating a dataflow to save data daily to Firestore, involving around 3 million records. However, I'm encountering an issue with the batch.commit() operation. Although no errors are raised during the process, However, when I count the number of the documents in Firestore. I got only 583,000. ( Expected to 1 Millions) but, when I rerun the process, the missing data appear. This issue happen sometime. I'm not sure what's wrong. Or is it possible to related to the write limitation of Firestore? Could anyone suggest how to prevent or solve this problem? I would greatly appreciate it.

```
var counter: Int = 0
var cnt: Int = 0
val batchsize = 100
val query = sc.bigQuerySelect(sql).map{
      row =>
        val username = row.getString("username")
        val name = row.getString("name")
        try {
          var firestore = FirestoreInstance.getFsInstance(firestore_project_id)
          if(counter == 0){
              batch = firestore.batch()
          }
          val featureData = name.replaceAll("[{}\"]", "").split(",")
          .map(_.split(":"))
          .map {
            case Array(k, v) =>
            val dataType = featureMap.get(k.trim)
            val parsedValue = dataType.flatMap {
              case "BOOLEAN" => 
                if(v.trim=="0")
                  Try("false".toBoolean).toOption
                else if (v.trim=="1")
                  Try("true".toBoolean).toOption
                else 
                  Try(v.trim.toBoolean).toOption
              case "INT32" => Try(v.trim.toInt).toOption
              case "FLOAT" => Try(v.trim.toDouble).toOption
              case _ => None
            }
            k.trim -> parsedValue.getOrElse(v.trim)
          }.toMap.asJava
          val updatedFeatureData = new JHashMap[String, Any](featureData)
          val updatedFeatureDataLatest = new JHashMap[String, Any](featureData)
          updatedFeatureData.put("ingestion_timestamp",insert_datetime)
          updatedFeatureDataLatest.put("ingestion_timestamp",insert_datetime)
          updatedFeatureData.put("expired_timestamp",expired_on)
          updatedFeatureData.put("document_id",insert_date.toString)
          updatedFeatureDataLatest.put("document_id","latest")
   
          val docRef: DocumentReference = firestore.collection(firestore_collection).document(username).collection(firestore_collection_group).document(insert_date.toString)
          batch.set(docRef, updatedFeatureData)
          val docRefLatest: DocumentReference = firestore.collection(firestore_collection).document(username).collection(firestore_collection_group).document("latest")
          batch.set(docRefLatest, updatedFeatureDataLatest)
          counter = counter + 1
          val lastLine  = counter + (cnt*batchsize)
          if((counter % batchsize == 0)){
            try{
                batch.commit()
                counter = 0
                cnt = cnt + 1
                batch = firestore.batch()

            }
            catch {
              case e: Exception =>
                print(e)

            }

          } 

        }
        catch {
          case e: Exception =>
            print(e)        
        }
    }
    batch.commit()
```

Here is the count command.

Expected Result ( Total of users): 1,000,000 documents

Actual Result: 583,000 documents

```
docs = db.collection_group("feature_tmp").where(field_path="document_id", op_string="==", value="latest").count().get()
```

I have found the error log in Firestore project.

It seem like it exceed the rate limit.

"This project has exceeded their maximum request_rate/bandwidth/document_rate for writes, please retry with exponential backoff. To learn more about limits, see 'Maximum writes per second per database' under 'Usage and limits' section of the support documentation"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZqSI.png)

Can anyone suggest?

- Why the error are not raised in dataflow.
- Can I have more details about the limit rate of Firestore.

Comment: "some data are missing when I check Firestore" isn't enough information to work with. Your question needs to contain specific details of what's not working the way you expect.  We should be able to duplicate the issue using the information you provide, including the data you're working with.

Comment: @DougStevenson sorry to not clarify it clear. 
1. I have the total data 1 Million users which I want to write it to Firestore. 
2. When I count the total documents in Firestore which this command. I got the result 583,000 which I expect to get 1 million document. 
docs = db.collection_group("feature_tmp").where(field_path="document_id", op_string="==", value="latest").count().get()

Comment: That's help information @P.pp. Can you edit your question (there's a link right under it) to include it? That way others are more likely to see it too, and it also gives you a chance to mark it up so the code is more readable.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Doug and Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.

Comment: The problem is we don't have your 1 million documents to work with, and we can't see what's special about the 583,000 that made it in.  This is an impossible situation to replicate on our own. We don't have data or error messages or anything else to understand what the problem might be.